# Suppose $X$ follows normal and $Y$ follows Bernoulli, wrt which measure does $(X,Y)=(-0.005,1)$ have a measure zero?

Tags: probability, continuous-data, discrete-data, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ follows standard normal distribution and $Y\in\{0,1\}$ follows Bernoulli(0.5),i.e., $Pr(Y=1)=0.5$. Intuitively, I know the point or event $(X,Y)=(-0.005,1)$ has a measure of zero. But I would like to more formally state with respect to which measure it has measure zero.

Is it proper to say that $(X,Y)=(-0.005,1)$ has a measure of zero with respect to the product of Lebesgue and counting measure?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent you should say so.  It is not necessary for a single point event to have measure $0$ but it may affect how you describe the  joint measure

Comment: @Henry I see, it's very helpful! Can you give a counterexample in which a single point in the joint distribution of a continuous and a discrete random variable have strictly positive measure?

Comment: No - that will not happen.  But If suppose $Y=1$ when $X\gt 0$ and $Y=0$ when $X\le 0$ then you would not call the joint measure a product of the two marginal measures.

Comment: @Henry Ok. Thanks! What's the proper way to say a single point having zero measure in this non-independent case then?

Comment: Perhaps $\lim_{x^+ \to -0.005} F_{X \mid Y = 1}(x) - \lim_{x^- \to -0.005} F_{X \mid Y = 1}(x) = 0$, where $F_{X \mid Y = 1}$ is the conditional CDF. A continuous distribution is formally one that has a continuous CDF. If the CDF is discontinuous then there is a mass point. For example, $\lim_{y^+ \to 1} F_{Y}(y) - \lim_{y^- \to 1} F_{Y}(y) = 0.5$ in this case.

Comment: $\Pr(X=-0.005,Y=1) \le \Pr(X=-0.005) =0$

Comment: @Henry Thanks! But what I want is a statement like "this argument goes through except for a point of ?? measure zero". $(-0.005,1)$ is the point where my proof fails.

Comment: @ecnmetrician Thank you very much! It's helpful.

Comment: @Henry Independence is not needed to answer this question.

Comment: @whuber - I know (and have said it twice before).  My point is that for some interpretations of "product" you do need independence

Comment: @Henry I don't follow that at all: the product of measures (in an appropriate category) is well-defined and not contingent on any sense of independence, which often cannot even be applied.